# Nuget package installation failed in VS 2017 (.net core)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, console-application, nuget-package

I created new Console App(.NET Core) and i am trying to add package with NuGet 
the package is : Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
When I click install I get this message:

```
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ConsoleApp1'.
```

Comment: I found the answer to the problem.
I need to install Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore package and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration included there.

Comment: Next time you ask a q uestion, you should also provide the exact error from the Package Manager log, since it shows which package failed for which reason

Comment: @maxman This really helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad that your problem is resolved, however I believe the solution you found may be coincidental as the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration has no dependencies on Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore, but  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore does depend on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration v1.0.0

I had similar issues yesterday, the same day that many Microsoft .net Core v2.0.0 NuGet packages were pushed to NuGet. I was inadvertently attempting to add v2.0.0 NuGet packages to my .net Core v1.x app, which gave the error

> Restoring packages for C:\Users\MrSlim_Is_Awesome\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\WebApplication4.csproj...
>   Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication4'.
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.1768927
>   ========== Finished ==========

The solution was to select a v1.x.x version of the relevant Microsoft NuGet package.